# Display Errors On Modal While Submitting The Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have asked previously the same question but I haven't provided much information.
This Time I am Specifying much of That.
The Below Represents The Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Design</title>
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script>
                function validatelogin(){
                    $unme2=document.getElementById("inputlUsername3").value;
                    $lpwd2=document.getElementById("inputlPassword3").value;
                    if($unme2=="" || $lpwd2=="")
                    {
                        $("#errorDiv1").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $("#errorDiv1").html("Please fill all fields.");
                        return false;    
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            //how to specify conditional php code here which i have written below this comment and check whether the particular username/password matches from the database?
                <?php
                        $msg ="";
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $uname=$_POST['txtuname'];
                $pwd2=$_POST['txtpwd2'];
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
                mysql_select_db("onlineshop",$con);
                $r=mysql_query("select password from users where username='$uname'",$con);
                $row = mysql_fetch_row($r);
                $val=$row[0];
                if($val!="")
                {
                    if($pwd2==$val)
                    {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['username']=$uname;
                        header("location:index.php");
                    }
                    else {
                        $msg="error";

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $msg="Error";
                }
            }
        ?>
        //how to represent the $msg value to javascript as $("#errorDiv1").html($msg);
                        }
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
            <div>
                <a href="#loginmodal" data-toggle=modal class=btn>Login</a>
            </div>            


            <div class="modal fade" id="loginmodal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" name="f1" action="index.php" id="loginform" onsubmit="return validatelogin();" method="post" role="form">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>Login</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="errorDiv1">

                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputUsername3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtuname" id="inputlUsername3" placeholder="Username">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                        <input type="password" name="txtpwd2" class="form-control" id="inputlPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="#registermodal" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">Register Here</a>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            </body>
    </html>
```

IF the validation process suggests any error then that error must represent on the modal and that modal shouldn't be closed.

whenever user press the login button, the message should be displayed on the modal.
The modal shouln't be closed until user provide the right username and password to that form.

Comment: Why did you put `php` code inside JS code? It looks messy. Wouldn't that be easier to use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)?

Comment: @AedixRhinedale would you show me how?

Comment: Try clicking the AJAX word on my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, Don't put PHP Code within the `<script>` tag.

> that modal shouldn't be closed

Replace: `<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">`
To: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-login">Login</button>`

Because when you submit, it will reload and as expected, the modal will disappear.

> the message should be displayed on the modal

Use AJAX:
Add this in the bottom of your body element.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.btn-login').click(function() {
    var post_url = 'Your_PHP_File_Here';

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: post_url,
      data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
      dataType: 'html',
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#errorDiv1').append(data);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Also, Add `echo $msg;` in your php after the `$msg = "some_message";` line.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would recommend to use `AJAX` request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Design</title>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                      $("#loginBtn").click(function(){
                        var userName = $("#inputlUsername3").val();
                        var password = $("#inputlPassword3").val();
                        if(userName && password) {
                         /*
                             response.txt is for demonstrate purpose.
                             You should change it to your server url and return true/false or 
                             any other response as per your need
                          */
                          $.ajax({url: "response.txt", success: function(result){
                              if(result === 'true') {
                                alert("Redirect it to dashboard");
                              } else {
                                alert("Show error");
                              }
                          }});
                        } else {
                          alert("Plz fill all the field");
                        }
                      });
                  });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
            <div>
                <a href="#loginmodal" data-toggle=modal class=btn>Login</a>
            </div>            


            <div class="modal fade" id="loginmodal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" name="f1" id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>Login</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="errorDiv1" onload="check();">
                                <?php echo $msg ?>
                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputUsername3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtuname" id="inputlUsername3" placeholder="Username">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                        <input type="password" name="txtpwd2" class="form-control" id="inputlPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="#registermodal" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">Register Here</a>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/X0Qrs84KNXRqWcgaisho?p=preview

Note : This is just for demonstration, how you can achieve. Instead of this you should use use post request and pass username and password to the server url.

```
$.post("yourServerUrl.php",{username:userName,password:password},function(result){
    //process request
});
```

Comment: what is response.txt? and can you tell me what will be the yourServerUrl.php file from which I provided in my question as of I am confusing what would I should make change at? I would recommend to have full code again.

Comment: In `plukr`, I can not provide the actual server url. So just to demonstrate ajax request, I fetch it from `response.txt` file in which you have to assume that server sends true(valid credentials) or false(wrong credentials) response.